# Callback methods (a XMLHttpRequest) in a Javascript Class Object

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I seem to get the following error: `this.getPageHTML is not a function` when executing my Modal class.

```
constructor(trigger) {
    this.trigger = trigger;
  }

  /**
   * Show Modal
   * @param {Element} trigger The element that is triggering the Modal.
   */

  showModal(trigger = this.trigger) {
      switch (trigger.dataset.modaltype) {
        case "media":
          this.getPageHTML(trigger.dataset.url, (response) => {
            const htmlContent = response.getElementById("content");
            const modalContent = document
              .getElementById("modal")
              .querySelector(".modal-window__content");

            // Inject response into Modal content
            modalContent.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlContent.innerHTML);

          });
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
  }

  getPageHTML(url, callback) {
    if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) return;
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Get the HTML
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.onloadstart = this.requestStarted;
    xhr.onprogress = this.updateRequestProgress;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        xhr.onload = function () {
          if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
            callback(this.responseXML);
          }
        };
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
```

Not sure why exactly my getPageHTML function is "not a function"?

In my main js file I call the class like this:

```
modalTriggers.forEach((trigger) => {
  trigger.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let modal = new Modal(trigger);
    modal.showModal();

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Could be something super obvious I'm missing here. I have tried assigning the "this.getPageHTML" to an anonomous function like "this.getPageHTML = function(trigger.dataset.url, response) {...}" but it seems to loose what "trigger" is.

Comment: in your constructor you have to bind `getPageHTML` method, add `this.getPageHTML = this.getPageHTML.bind(this)` inside `constructor` method.

Comment: Write `debugger` before this.getPageHTML and see what happens - if it is a typo or some context issue

Comment: @ROOT or `this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this)` as `this` is undefined in `showModal` function. So we should bind this to `showModal`

Comment: What is `modalTriggers` ?

Comment: @Kenny, that's a typo on my end, I was writing fast, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I don't see why this code wouldn't work. Did you use a debugger (or `console.log` statement) to verify what the value of `this` is in the `showModal()` call?

Comment: Thanks guys :), so in the `showModal()` function, **this** is consoling the a tag element, which is correct as the **modalTriggers** are a list of all elements from a querySelectorAll() buuuut in the switch statement in the same function, **this** is the window element?

Also I went ahead and bind the two methods in my constructor as ROOT and @kenny suggested but still no luck yet :(. `getPageHTML()` is still erroring "not a function"